# Can I use the sub-query in the FROM in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can I write the T-SQL like below

```
select *
 FROM (select * 
        from TableA 
       where FieldA = 1
       )
where FieldB > 10
```

which means I want to query from the results of another query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes** you can

```
select * 
FROM  ( select * from TableA where FieldA=1 ) sub
where FieldB > 10
```

*Just remember to give the sub select an alias.*

Comment: Morning Ponies. The query will not compile if you leave out the table alias... X-)

Comment: I've only had that experience with MySQL - gonna test that tomorrow

Comment: Just did it on my PC... **Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 12 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.**

Comment: Morning?!  Ah, cuz you're in South Africa.  It's 9ish PM here in Canada

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate out your sub-queries you can also use Common Table Expressions (CTE's) which help make your code more readable:

```
WITH Foo (FieldA, FieldB, FieldC) AS
(
    SELECT FieldA, FieldB, FieldC
    FROM TableA
    WHERE FieldA=1
)

SELECT *
FROM Foo
WHERE FieldB > 10
```

The downside is you will have to explicitly name your columns. However, this actually makes your code faster so it's not always a bad thing.